# PHP 7 Error on old theme - Prestashop 1.6 / Thirtybees: 'Cannot use string offset as an array'

Tags: php, arrays, themes, prestashop

I'm trying to install an 'old' (2018) Prestashop 1.6 theme on PHP 7.2 but it seems that part of the theme code is deprecated PHP wise. Maybe the way the array is declared? Can you please help as I think line 1263 needs to rewritten:

```
Cannot use string offset as an array
in file modules/leotempcp/leotempcp.php at line 1263


1261:        if ($directories) {
1262:            foreach ($directories as $dir) {
1263:                $output['skins'][basename($dir)]['name'] = $this->l(basename($dir));
1264:                if (file_exists($dir.'/icon.png')) {
1265:                    $output['skins'][basename($dir)]['icon'] = _PS_BASE_URL_._THEME_DIR_.'css/skins/'.basename($dir).'/icon.png';
1266:                }
1267:            }
1268:        }
```

Your help is appreciated

Comment: Could be probably fixed with `$output['skins'][(string)basename($dir)]['name'] = $this->l(basename($dir));`

Comment: Alas, still same error, this time on the provided code snippet

Comment: Have you tried to dump out your $output variable to see which index in the chain might not exist or exist as a string instead of an array?